# Id field should be number only or contains a letter?

Tags: database, database-design

It's a common question. Every table has atleast a primary key, so which type of data that primary key should be? Number only like 1/2/3/4 or we add some letters like A1/A2/A3 to distinguish which id belongs to which table?

Comment: Choosing a primary key for a table has been debated many times over, you can find everything with a simple google search. The approach you suggest is not very good, because you would have to generate your values manually. Let the database do what it's already good at in case you end up using a surrogate key (which will often be the case). And if you use a natural key, the data type depends on the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key is a business key then the business needs should be the determining factor. Alphanumeric keys are often easier for people to use. Ideally a key should be familiar, simple and stable.

If the key is a surrogate then what's most important is the efficiency of generating and storing it. Most often it is just a sequential number.